# iPhone product IDs in price tiers 80 and over are failing

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm working in sandbox mode, and everything's working great.  However, when I try to add a Product in price tier 80-85 ($499-$999), Apple returns the Product ID as invalid.  Switching it to something lower in iTunesConnect (such as 79) makes it valid, but putting it back at 80 or above immediately causes it to fail.  Does anyone know if we need to get direct approval from Apple for PIDs in this range?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now. Have you maybe found a solution since you asked this question?

Answer (score 0):

It should work now. I filed a bug report with apple on this and they resolved the issue today. Just tried it myself, all products with tiers 80 and above are available for purchase.